# Regarding the scope and garbage collection in Spring bean container

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

I am new to Spring and I am currently using it in one of my projects. I learned that the Spring container holds all the beans and the scope of all the beans is `"singleton"` by default. I can change the scope either in the `application-context.xml` file or using the annotation `@Scope`.
I furthermore learned that if a class has the scope `"prototype"`, the Spring container will instantiate a new object of this class whenever needed.

What I don't understand: How is garbage collection handled. Will the created objects be garbage collected if they are no longer required or will they still be kept in the container. Obviously, I do not want many objects to be created and kept in order to keep memory usage low.

Answer (score 40):

From Spring documentation ([*3.5.2 The prototype scope*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)):

> In contrast to the other scopes, Spring **does not manage** the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean: the container instantiates, configures, and otherwise assembles a prototype object, and hands it to the client, with **no further record of that prototype instance**.

Simply put - once you create and obtain a reference to `prototype` scoped bean, it is the only reference existing in the JVM. Once this references gets out of scope, the object will be garbage collected:

```
void bar() {
  Object foo = ctx.getBean("foo")
}
```

The moment you leave `bar()` method there aren't any other references to new instance of `foo`, which means it is eligible for garbage collection. The consequence of this model is:

> Thus, although *initialization* lifecycle callback methods are called on all objects regardless of scope, in the case of prototypes, configured destruction lifecycle callbacks are *not* called.

Comment: I am trying to understand this. So does it make @PreDestroy not relevant for a prototype bean?

Comment: @Larsen Yes, this is what it means.

Answer (score 4):

The container doesn't keep a reference to instantiated beans, the code that's using them does.

If nothing else references the bean (roughly), it's eligible for GC.