# What is difference between singleton and prototype bean?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

i'm new to spring and i read this :

> Basically a bean has scopes which defines their existence on the application
>
> Singleton: means single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IOC container.
>
> Prototype: means a single bean definition to any number of object instances.

So What is the  "object instance" .

Comment: Good ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s05.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Prototype scope** = A new object is created each time it is injected/looked up. It will use `new SomeClass()` each time.

**Singleton scope** = *(Default)* The same object is returned each time it is injected/looked up. Here it will instantiate one instance of `SomeClass` and then return it each time.

**See also:**

- [Spring Bean Scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599216/spring-bean-scopes)

Comment: and how it affects the application? having single instance per context vs having one instance per injection? will there be any concurrency/thread issues?

Comment: Question on the above answer:
In case of singleton scope one object is created in the lifetime of a context at the startup (or can be lazy'd). What about prototype scope? Whether any object would be created at the context startup? or this is complete request based?

Answer (score 34):

Let's just simply look this up through code.

Following is a TennisCoach Bean with default **`singleton`** Scope

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

    public TennisCoach(){

    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFortuneService(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        return "Practice your backhand volley";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return "Tennis Coach says : "+fortuneService.getFortune();
    }

}
```

Following is a TennisCoach Bean with **prototype** scope

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

    public TennisCoach(){
        System.out.println(">> TennisCoach: inside default constructor");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFortuneService(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        System.out.println(">> Tennis Coach: inside setFortuneService");
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        return "Practice your backhand volley";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return "Tennis Coach says : "+fortuneService.getFortune();
    }

}
```

Following is a Main class :

```
public class AnnotationDemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // read spring config file
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

       // get the bean from the spring container
       Coach theCoach = context.getBean("tennisCoach",Coach.class);
       Coach alphaCoach = context.getBean("tennisCoach",Coach.class);
       // call a method on the bean
       System.out.println("Are the two beans same :" + (theCoach==alphaCoach));

       System.out.println("theCoach : " + theCoach);
       System.out.println("alphaCoach: "+ alphaCoach);


       context.close()

    }
}
```

For **singleton** scope the output is :

```
Are the two beans same :true
theCoach : com.springdemo.TennisCoach@2a53142
alphaCoach: com.springdemo.TennisCoach@2a53142
```

For **prototype** scope the output is :

```
Are the two beans same :false
theCoach : com.springdemo.TennisCoach@1b37288
alphaCoach: com.springdemo.TennisCoach@1a57272
```

Comment: good example, when will you prefer which scope?

Answer (score 15):

Adding to the above..dont get confuse with the java singleton.
according to JAVA spec singleton means only one instance of that bean will be created per JVM.
but in spring singleton means one instance for that particular bean will be created per application context.
so if your app has more than one context you can still have more than one instance for that bean.

Comment: I have a question based on your answer above. Say I am working in a MVC web app project . If I use singleton here for each session or request there is a new object created? where as the singleton scope is within the context and also within that session?

Comment: partly correct partly wrong. See its all depends which scope you are using while defining the bean in the configuration file. By default java makes the scope as singleton.
There five scopes available:-
1.singleton – Return a single bean instance per Spring IoC container
2.prototype – Return a new bean instance each time when requested
3.request – Return a single bean instance per HTTP request. *
4.session – Return a single bean instance per HTTP session. *
5.globalSession – Return a single bean instance per global HTTP session. *

Answer (score 4):

They are both creational design patterns.

Singleton, will create a new instance in the first call, and return it in subsequent calls.

Prototype will return a new instance each time.

Comment: both creational design patterns?
for singleton yes but for prototype no. Spring doesn't implement the prototype design pattern by the GoF

Answer (score 4):

**Singleton Scope:** With Singleton scope, one and only one instance of a bean is created with the provided bean definition and for subsequent requests for the same bean, Spring container will return the same instance .

From the Spring documentation:

> .. when you define a bean definition and it is scoped as a singleton,
>   the Spring IoC container creates exactly one instance of the object
>   defined by that bean definition. This single instance is stored in a
>   cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and
>   references for that named bean return the cached object...

Example:
Lets say, we have defined a bean `accountDao` as below:

```
<bean id="accountDao" class="" />
```

And another two beans, which uses this `accountDao` bean

```
<bean id="someBean" ref="accountDao" /> 
<bean id="anotherBean" ref="accountDao" />
```

Spring will initially create `accountDao`bean and cache it. And then for `someBean` as well as `anotherBean`, it will provide the same instance of `accountDao`.

**Note:** If no scope is specified with bean definition, Singleton is the default scope.

**Prototype Scope:** For prototype scope, for each request for the bean, a new instance of the bean will be created and returned. This is similar to calling ***new*** operator in java for a class.

Example:
Lets say, we have defined a bean `accountDao` as below:

```
<bean id="accountDao" class="" scope="prototype"/>
```

And another two beans, which uses this `accountDao` bean

```
<bean id="someBean" ref="accountDao" /> 
<bean id="anotherBean" ref="accountDao" />
```

For someBean and anotherBean, Spring will return two separate instance of the accountDao object.

One important difference is, for prototype scope, Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of the bean, clean up needs to be done by the client code.

From the Spring documentation:

> Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean: the
>   container instantiates, configures, and otherwise assembles a
>   prototype object, and hands it to the client, with no further record
>   of that prototype instance. Thus, although initialization lifecycle
>   callback methods are called on all objects regardless of scope, in the
>   case of prototypes, configured destruction lifecycle callbacks are not
>   called. The client code must clean up prototype-scoped objects and
>   release expensive resources that the prototype bean(s) are holding.

Comment: How can i perform cleanup for prototype bean. As per my understanding all cleanup should taken care by JVM.

Comment: @Sigstop, Correct. You will find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419073/regarding-the-scope-and-garbage-collection-in-spring-bean-container useful.

Answer (score 3):

1. Singleton scope is default.
2. Singleton beans are created during initialization of app context and same bean is returned always.
3. Prototype bean is created when ever it is called. Each time it is called we get a new object.

Note : Bean with any scope will be created if it is referred by other beans and called using Application context.

Example code to check this.

```
public class PrototypeClass {

        PrototypeClass()
        {
            System.out.println("prototype class is created"+this.toString());
        }

    }
```

This will print the relevant text when constructor is invoked.

for the below code

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   PrototypeClass pct= (PrototypeClass) context.getBean("protoClass");
}
```

> prototype class is createdSpring.PrototypeClass@29774679 prototype
>   class is createdSpring.PrototypeClass@3ffc5af1 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@5e5792a0 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@26653222 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@3532ec19 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@68c4039c prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@ae45eb6 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@59f99ea prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@27efef64 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@6f7fd0e6 prototype class is
>   createdSpring.PrototypeClass@47c62251

Bean definition is

```
<bean id="protoClass" class="Spring.PrototypeClass" scope="prototype</bean>
```

Now I changed the scope in bean definition to singleton . Constructor is called only once  during initialization of context.  Next I removed the scope attribute and observed same behavior as singleton.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add some additional information that can help us to find out the meaning of "object instance" in mentioned sentences. This paragraph from Spring Doc try to define "object instance":

> When you create a bean definition, you create a recipe for creating **actual** **instances of the class defined by that bean definition**. The idea that a bean definition is a recipe is important, because it means that,
>   as with a class, you can create many **object instances** from a single recipe.

Therefore, as mentioned in above section, each bean definition canor  be considered as a Class(in terms of Object Oriented). According the data that you defined in it (such as scope, ...) this class (or bean definition) may have just one object instances (the singleton scope by only one shared instance) or any number of object instances(for example the prototype scope by creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made).

Answer (score 2):

**Prototype scope:** A new object is created each time it is injected.
**Singleton scope:** The same object is returned each time it is injected.

Prototype scope is used for all beans that are stateful, while the singleton scope should be used for stateless beans.
Let me explain with my example. Please copy and run it by yourself to get a clear understanding. 
Consider an interface Coach.

```
public interface Coach {

    public String getDailyWorkout();

    public String getDailyFortune();

}
```

We have another class called TrackCoach which implements Coach.

```
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {

    private FortuneService fortuneService;


    public TrackCoach(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        return "Run a hard 5k";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return "Just Do it: " + fortuneService.getFortune();
    }    
}
```

Now there is a FortuneService interface.

```
public interface FortuneService {

    public String getFortune();

}
```

It is implemented by our class HappyFortuneService.

```
public class HappyFortuneService implements FortuneService {

    @Override
    public String getFortune() {
        return "Today is your lucky day!";
    }

}
```

Let's wire the two classes and inject an object bean of one class into another using Xml. Let's perform dependency injection. Note that we can do this using java annotation too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <!-- Define your beans here -->

    <!--  define the dependency  -->
    <bean id = "myFortuneService"
        class = "com.luv2code.springdemo.HappyFortuneService">
    </bean>

    <bean id = "myCoach"
        class = "com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach"
        scope = "singleton">


        <!-- set up construction injection -->
        <constructor-arg ref = "myFortuneService" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Notice that `scope = singleton`.

Now let's define our BeanScopeDemoApp, which has our main method.

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class BeanScopeDemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // load the spring configuration file 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beanScope-applicationContext.xml");

        // retrieve bean from spring container 
        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", Coach.class);

        Coach alphaCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", Coach.class);

        // check if they are the same 
        boolean result = (theCoach == alphaCoach);

        // print out the results 
        System.out.println("\nPointing to the same object: " + result);

        System.out.println("\nMemory location for theCoach: " + theCoach);

        System.out.println("\nMemory location for alphaCoach: " + alphaCoach +"\n");

        // close the context 
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Once you run the above code, you will see the following results:

```
Pointing to the same object: true

Memory location for theCoach: com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach@16515bb7

Memory location for alphaCoach: com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach@16515bb7
```

It's pointing the same object and occupies the same memory location after calling it twice. 
Now let's change the `scope = prototype` in our Xml file, save it and run the BeanScopeDemoApp again.
You will see the following results:

```
Pointing to the same object: false

Memory location for theCoach: com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach@6d4d203d

Memory location for alphaCoach: com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach@627fbcda
```

It's pointing the different object and occupies the different memory locations after calling it twice.
This would be a graphical illustration of what i have just said. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: nicely explained. but could you please tell us, when should we use singleton scope and when should we use prototype scope?

Comment: All the answers tell us "what" are singleton and prototype, but no one told us "when" to use singleton and prototype. What's the advantage vs disadvantages of using the either?

Comment: When you want to maintain the state then use "prototype".

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is same instance across application

Prototype is new instance for every new request of getBean

Answer (score 0):

When a bean has a prototype scope, it means that a new instance of the bean is created each time it is requested.

Singleton scope, where a single instance of the bean is created and reused and it's at application level, in the prototype scope a new instance of the bean is created on each request.

Let us with an example,
**Singleton scope with Employee bean,**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean          //by default scope is singleton
  public Employee employee(){
      return new Employee();
  }
}
```

**Main class to call employee bean,**

```
  Employee employee = applicationContext.getBean(Employee.class);
  employee.setName("Singleton scope test");
  System.out.println(employee.getName());
  
  Employee employeeBean = applicationContext.getBean(Employee.class);
  System.out.println(employeeBean.getName());
```

Output should be,

```
Singleton scope test
Singleton scope test
```

In the both object, it will return same instance, it won't be create new one.

**Prototype bean scope,**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public Employee employee(){
      return new Employee();
  }
}
```

**Main class to call employee bean,**

```
  Employee employee = applicationContext.getBean(Employee.class);
  employee.setName("Prototype scope");
  System.out.println(employee.getName());
  
  Employee employeeBean = applicationContext.getBean(Employee.class);
  System.out.println(employeeBean.getName());
```

Output should be,

```
Prototype scope
null
```

In the first getBean call setting the name so it's printing Prototype scope and when it's calling second time getBean, it's not being set name so it's creating new object and printing name as null.