# Spring Bean Scopes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can someone explain what the scopes are in Spring beans I've always just used 'prototype' but are there other parameters I can put in place of that?

Example of what I'm talking about

```
<bean id="customerInfoController" class="com.action.Controller" scope="prototype">
    <property name="accountDao" ref="accountDao"/>
    <property name="utilityDao" ref="utilityDao"/>
    <property name="account_usageDao" ref="account_usageDao"/>  
</bean>
```

Comment: See [Bean Scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/

Comment: [A much better and official documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Comment: Very good explanation here: http://codeflex.co/java-spring-scopes-explained/

Comment: I'd like to add an update: As per the new Spring release, docs. spring now has 6 scopes: Singleton, Prototype, Request, Session, Application, WebSocket.

[**recommended official spring doc. link**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)
...and...
in case if you are not comfortable with the official spring doc's link, here's [_another simple explanation_](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-scopes/)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

From the [spring specs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html), there are five types of bean scopes supported :

> **1. singleton(default*)**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring
>   IoC container.
>
> **2. prototype**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
>
> **3. request**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP
>   request; that is each and every HTTP request will have its own
>   instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition.
>   Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **4. session**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session.
>   Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **5. global session**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP
>   Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only
>   valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

*default means when no scope is explicitly provided in the `<bean />` tag.
read more about them here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: "Web-aware Spring ApplicationContext" is a [WebApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) that extends ApplicationContext. In addition to the extra scopes mentioned by @JunedAhsan, there is a `getServletContext()` method to `Return the standard Servlet API ServletContext for this application.`

Answer (score 36):

In Spring, bean scope is used to decide which type of bean instance should be returned from Spring container back to the caller.

5 types of bean scopes are supported :

1. **Singleton :** It returns a single bean instance per Spring IoC container.This single instance is stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and references for that named bean return the cached object.If no bean scope is specified in bean configuration file, **default** to singleton.
   [image]
2. **Prototype** : It returns a new bean instance each time when requested. It does not store any cache version like singleton.
   [image]
3. **Request** : It returns a single bean instance per HTTP request.

   [image]
4. **Session** : It returns a single bean instance per HTTP session (User level session).
5. **GlobalSession** : It returns a single bean instance per global HTTP session. It is only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext (Application level session).

In most cases, you may only deal with the Spring’s core scope – **singleton** and **prototype**, and the default scope is **singleton**.

Answer (score 12):

Just want to update, that in Spring 5, as mentioned in [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes), Spring supports 6 scopes, four of which are available only if you use a web-aware ApplicationContext.

> **singleton** (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
>
> **prototype**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
>
> **request**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is, each HTTP request has its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **session**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **application**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a ServletContext. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **websocket**
>   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a WebSocket. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Comment: There are total 6 scopes and top two can be used without web-aware? If so then how do you say that out of 6, five of which are available only if you use a web-aware ApplicationContext?

Comment: You are right. He made a mistake, he said 5 instead of 4.

Answer (score 7):

The *Spring documentation* describes the [following standard scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes):

> **singleton**: (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
>
> **prototype**: Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
>
> **request**: Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is, each HTTP request has its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **session**: Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **global session**: Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Additional custom scopes can also be created and configured using a `CustomScopeConfigurer`. An example would be the `flow` scope added by Spring Webflow.

By the way, you argues that you always used `prototype` what I find strange. The standard scope is `singleton` and in the application I develop, I rarely need the prototype scope. You should maybe take a look at this.

Answer (score 6):

Detailed explanation for each scope can be found here in [Spring bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes). Below is the summary

**Singleton** - 
(Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.

**prototype** - Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.

**request** - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is, each HTTP request has its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

**session** - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

**global session** - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 3):

A short example what is the difference between `@Scope("singleton")` (default) and `@Scope("prototype")`:

DAO class:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class Manager {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope("singleton")
    public Manager getManager(){
        return new Manager();
    }
}
```

and MainApp:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.example.demo");
        context.refresh();

        Manager firstManager = context.getBean(Manager.class);
        firstManager.setName("Karol");

        Manager secondManager = context.getBean(Manager.class);
        System.out.println(secondManager.getName());
    }

}
```

In this example the result is: `Karol` even if we set this name only for `firstManager` object. It's because Spring IoC container created one instance of object. However when we change scope to `@Scope("prototype")` in Configuration class then result is: `null` because Spring IoC container creates a new bean instance of the object when request for that bean is made.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope) of `Spring-Cloud-Config` there is one extra scope next to the existing five. It is `@RefreshScope`.

This is the short description of `RefreshScope`:

> When there is a configuration change, a Spring @Bean that is marked as
>   @RefreshScope gets special treatment. This feature addresses the
>   problem of stateful beans that only get their configuration injected
>   when they are initialized. For instance, if a DataSource has open
>   connections when the database URL is changed via the Environment, you
>   probably want the holders of those connections to be able to complete
>   what they are doing. Then, the next time something borrows a
>   connection from the pool, it gets one with the new URL.
>
> Sometimes, it might even be mandatory to apply the @RefreshScope
>   annotation on some beans which can be only initialized once. If a bean
>   is "immutable", you will have to either annotate the bean with
>   @RefreshScope or specify the classname under the property key
>   spring.cloud.refresh.extra-refreshable.
>
> Refresh scope beans are lazy proxies that initialize when they are
>   used (that is, when a method is called), and the scope acts as a cache
>   of initialized values. To force a bean to re-initialize on the next
>   method call, you must invalidate its cache entry.
>
> The RefreshScope is a bean in the context and has a public
>   refreshAll() method to refresh all beans in the scope by clearing the
>   target cache. The /refresh endpoint exposes this functionality (over
>   HTTP or JMX). To refresh an individual bean by name, there is also a
>   refresh(String) method.

Answer (score 0):

About prototype bean(s) :

> The client code must clean up prototype-scoped objects and release
>   expensive resources that the prototype bean(s) are holding. To get the
>   Spring container to release resources held by prototype-scoped beans,
>   try using a custom bean post-processor, which holds a reference to
>   beans that need to be cleaned up.

ref : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Answer (score 0):

Also [websocket](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) scope is added:

Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a WebSocket. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

As the per the content of the documentation, there is also thread scope, that is not registered by default.