# Real World use case of bean scopes

Tags: spring

I am learning Spring, I learned about bean scopes - what are the real world use cases for each of them, I am not able to get any help. please help when to use Singleton, Prototype , Request and Session scopes in Spring.

Comment: This link might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599216/spring-bean-scopes

Answer (score 33):

- **Singleton**: It returns a single bean instance per Spring IoC container.This single instance is stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and references for that named bean return the cached object. If no bean scope is specified in the configuration file, singleton is default. **Real world example**: connection to a database
- **Prototype**: It returns a new bean instance each time it is requested. It does not store any cache version like singleton. **Real world example**: declare configured form elements (a textbox configured to validate names, e-mail addresses for example) and get "living" instances of them for every form being created
- **Request**: It returns a single bean instance per HTTP request. **Real world example**: information that should only be valid on one page like the result of a search or the confirmation of an order. The bean will be valid until the page is reloaded.
- **Session**: It returns a single bean instance per HTTP session (User level session). **Real world example**: to hold authentication information getting invalidated when the session is closed (by timeout or logout). You can store other user information that you don't want to reload with every request here as well.
- **GlobalSession**: It returns a single bean instance per global HTTP session. It is only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext (Application level session). It is similar to the Session scope and really only makes sense in the context of portlet-based web applications. The portlet specification defines the notion of a global Session that is shared among all of the various portlets that make up a single portlet web application. Beans defined at the global session scope are bound to the lifetime of the global portlet Session.