# How to use field in @Component class simultaneously?

Tags: java, spring

Following this code:

```
@Component
public class ClassC extends ClassA<T> implements ClassB {

    private String preferredDateTimeFormat = null;
```

My process is using this class after calling a request from client.

Per each request I want to keep the `preferredDateTimeFormat` value, what is actually being made that, the `preferredDateTimeFormat` variable is being used for all of my requests.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: you can make your question clearer

Comment: How to make `preferredDateTimeFormat` field to be different per each `ClassC` (a @Component) instance

Comment: you mean have a different value?

Comment: Each instance of this `@Component` should have different value for `preferredDateTimeFormat` variable

Comment: You want to annotate your class with a scope (request). As Spring per default initializes singleton beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@Scope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) on your class with value = `request`

like this

```
@Component
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ClassC extends ClassA<T> implements ClassB {

  private String preferredDateTimeFormat = null;
```

You can find more information on Spring Bean Scopes [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-scope-example-using-scope-annotation-and-xml-for-singleton-prototype-request-session-global-session-and-application-scope-with-scoped-proxy#request)

Comment: That one worked, could you please give me some short info about the purpose of - `@Scope(value="request", proxyMode =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.

You can define a Request Scope bean and place the `preferredDateTimeFormat` there.

OR

You can define ThreadLocal property and place the value there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you mean you want a ClassC instance per request or a new instance everytime it is used but you might want to look into the `@Scope` annotation with its values `Prototype` and `Request`.

See [Spring Bean Scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599216/spring-bean-scopes).