# Using EntityManager as an autowired field in a Spring Repository

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, thread-safety

I'm working on a legacy codebase and saw something unsettling in our custom repositories. `EntityManager` is autowired into the repos directly. For example:

```
@Repository
public class OperationRepository {

    // Yikes
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private QOperation operation = QOperation.operation;

    @Autowired
    public OperationRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Operation> findOneByIdAndType(Long operationId, OperationType type) {
        JPAQuery<Operation> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
        QOperation qOperation = QOperation.operation;
        query.select(operation).from(operation)
                .where(
                        operation.type.eq(type),
                ...
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this is dangerous since `EntityManager` is not threadsafe and is being managed here as a field. I don't see an explicit definition in any of our configuration files to provide an `EntityManager` bean so am not sure what Spring does in this case.

I am going to start on the fix for using `@PersistenceContext` here instead but wanted to understand what the impact is on this being in production for so long and what consequences might have come from it.

Would we be limiting our connection pool size to the number of single entitymanagers in our repository beans? Are there any other dangers it could have caused? Or am I making too much of it?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the configuration of your application context, which might get configured by Spring Boot if you are using that, but in general and with a typicals setup this is not a problem.

In such a setup the application context doesn't contain a single (or a limited set of) `EntityManager` instance but an `EntityManagerFactory` which can create `EntityManager` instances on demand.
And you don't get injected a normal `EntityManager` either, but a proxy which will point to different instances upon different calls, typically so that each thread has its own `EntityManager` and after a web request is completed the next request handled by the same thread gets a fresh instance.

If you are still concerned, I recommend to use a debugger to inspect the `EntityManager` and confirm that it is indeed a proxy and that it delegates to different actual instances for different threads.

You might also want to take a look at this question about Spring Scopes which is the underlying abstraction for this: [Spring Bean Scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599216/spring-bean-scopes)

Comment: I was not aware of the proxy pattern. Debugger shows: `shared entitymanager proxy for target factory` for the EntityManager

Comment: very interesting. So `OperationRepository` is still a singleton but the EntityManager is a proxy. In that case is this a valid pattern or should the switch still be made to `PersistenceContext` and why?

Comment: This is perfectly valid. I'm not aware of any benefit of using `PersistenceContext`