# Converting spring xml to java configuration with implicit setter autowiring

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-java-config

I want to convert spring xml to java configuration.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   default-autowire="byName">

  <bean name="car" type="Car" />
  <bean name="tire" type="Tire" />

</beans>
```

I have two classes: Car and Tire.

```
public class Tire {
    private String age;
}

public class Car {
    private Tire tire;

    // Spring calls this setter because default-autowire="byName" of xml configuration
    public void setTire(Tire newTire) {
        this.tire = newTire;
    }
}
```

I'm **not** using @Inject nor @Autowired annotations, but spring **autowires** and it works.
How can I change xml to java configuration **without** modifying Car and Tire classes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly a fix to Salman's answer.

You can indeed use a configuration class to achieve your requirements, but you **must** inject `tire` bean in `car` bean and not an arbitrary `Tire`. You can use the fact that it is legal for a configuration class to have its own beans injected into itself :

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {
    @Autowired
    Tire tire;

    @Bean 
    public Car car() {
        Car car =new Car();
        car.setTire(tire);
        return car;
    }
    @Bean
    public Tire tire() {
        return new Tire();
    }
}
```

That way, you can leave both `Car.java` and `Tire.java` untouched (no annotations there) and still have `tire` bean injected in `car` bean.

Answer (score 0):

This is psuedo/sample code (*may have syntax errors*).

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import Car;
import Tire;

@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {
  @Bean 
  public Car car() {
    Car car =new Car();
    car.setTire(tire());
    return car;
  }
  @Bean
  public Tire tire() {
    return new Tire();
  }
}
```

And here is how to access the context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ApplicationContext ctx = 
   new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyAppConfig.class);
   Car car = ctx.getBean(Car.class);
}
```

ref: [spring_java_based_configuration](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm)

Comment: That's wrong : `@Bean` annotation is not magic enough to break what is coded. You **explicitely** write `car.setTire(tire())`. As tire returns **a new Tire** on each invocation, the one you inject in `car` bean is **not** `tire` bean.

Comment: You may need to look up the spring concepts [prototype and singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058365/what-is-difference-between-singleton-and-prototype-bean). You may use Serge's answer if it fits your requirements better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Salman . Indeed, my specific question is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192940/converting-spring-xml-to-java-configuration-with-implicit-setter-autowiring-and)

Answer (score 0):

Here, the car() method asks for a Tire as a parameter. When Spring
calls car() to create the Car bean, it autowires a Tire into the
configuration method. Then the body of the method can use it however it sees fit. With this technique, the car() method can still inject the Tire into the
Car setTire method without explicitly referring to the Tire @Bean
method.

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

@Bean
public Car car(Tire tire) {
    Car car=new Car();
    car.setTire(tire);
    return car;
}
@Bean
public Tire tire() {
    return new Tire();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ricardo . Indeed, my specific question is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192940/converting-spring-xml-to-java-configuration-with-implicit-setter-autowiring-and)