# Is it possible to hold prototype reference inside singleton bean and singleton reference inside prototype bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

If both are possible in Spring, what is the difference between runtime functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can wire prototype beans in singleton but there are some pitfalls.

Here is a good example.

https://prasanthnath.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/injecting-a-prototype-bean-into-a-singleton-bean/

Comment: What about the reverse i.e Singleton inside prototype

Comment: You can do that as well. The difference between the functionality is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058365/what-is-difference-between-singleton-and-prototype-bean