# Why Do We Need Prototype Scope In Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am thinking about `@scope("prototype")` scope but I don't get it because we already have the `new` keyword. Both of them create a new instance of an object in runtime. What is the advantage of using `prototype`? Is it easier to reallocate than using `new`? Am I doing something wrong when I create new object with using the `new` keyword?

I'm trying to understand the advantages of it.

I found this question but it does not explain the advantages / disadvantages of `new` and `prototype`: [What is the difference between bean with scope prototype and new Object in singleton bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333094/what-is-the-difference-between-bean-with-scope-prototype-and-new-object-in-singl)

Comment: Did you read the first answer to that question?

Comment: Yes of course. Can you tell me what is advantage of using prototype scope with regarding this message?

Comment: You need to read [the basic information about what Spring DI/IoC is for](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `new` keyword you are creating an java object but it is not a spring bean and will not present in spring container. But if you use `@scope("prototype")` for every request a new spring bean is provided. for more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866571/difference-between-javabean-and-spring-bean)

**What is a spring bean?**

> A Spring bean is basically an object managed by Spring. More specifically, it is an object that is instantiated, configured and otherwise managed by a Spring Framework container. Spring beans are defined in a Spring configuration file (or, more recently, by using annotations), instantiated by the Spring container, and then injected into your application.

**Advantages of spring bean?**

1) By default all spring beans are immutable and spring IOC container will manage them

2) By using dependency injection you can inject the beans into any other object easily

3) Dependency injection makes testing easier. The injection can be done through constructor.

4) If you are using [spring boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) then you can inject the values from `application.yml` or `application.properties` into spring beans by using `@Value` annotation

Comment: that dependes on injection point.

Comment: What is the advantages of initializing inside of spring container? Both of them uses heap memory space. Both of them use garbage collector to reallocate. Thanks by the way

Comment: @Berkin the point is that they can participate in Spring dependency injection. As well as other Spring features like DB transaction boundaries, security checks, etc. You have to let Spring manage the bean for it to participate in all the features Spring provides.

Comment: updated my answer @Berkin

Comment: @Deadpool what if you have statefull bean that contains eg current state and cannot be shared between different processes? You need separate instance every time. Thus prototype.

Comment: I agree with you @Antoniossss  but OP is more over looking for advantages between new keyword object and spring beans

Comment: Sorry, mention was to berkin..... your answer is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Its straightforward. In some scenarios you might need separate instance in every bean. It is almost equal to creating with `new` when needed with an exception that you have the ability to inject dependencies to whatever you have marked as prototype.

Answer (score 2):

For instance you have a token and you should one time consume so every time new instance create to application context for this reason you can use this type.

Comment: Yeah but we can do such things with using new keyword, can't we? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can but when you use with new keyword throughout spring IOC can't include your instance,You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

One of the key benefits of using Spring is that it removes the need to instantiate objects directly via `new`, rather objects are created as Spring components/beans and registered in the Spring Application Context - this leads to to software components that are available to be composed  together with each other via injection, and leads to easier unit testing and more flexible software.

The spring  prototype scope means a new instance of the spring component will be created (by the spring runtime/container) each time it is needed and registgered in the spring application context. Ultimately Spring is creating an object  and it is stored on the heap like any other object, but the abstraction layer that the Spring Container provides in terms of being able to define and "wire" together software components has profound advantages over using naked `new` to create objects inside other objects.